# Is 'prudent vigour' an oxymoron?

Tags: meaning-in-context, oxymoron

I was reading the *History of the Fall and Decline of the Roman Empire* (Edward Gibbon, 1776) when I encountered the phrase 'prudent vigour'. Prudent means carefulness and showing forethought while vigour means energy and enthusiasm. Aren't these two things incompatible? And hence the phrase is an oxymoron.

> The experience of Augustus added weight to these salutary reflections, and effectually convinced him that, by the **prudent vigor** of his counsels, it would be easy to secure every concession which the safety or the dignity of Rome might require from the most formidable barbarians.

Comment: I don't see prudence and vigour as being particularly oxymoronic. Most likely prudent hotheadedness and languorous vigour would be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is an oxymoron, but note the definition:

> *Rhetoric.* A figure of speech in which a pair of opposed or markedly contradictory terms are placed in conjunction for emphasis.
>
> OED

The two terms need to be read together: they are both apposite. In this case, the counsels were vigorous **and** prudent, presumably arguing strongly for a course of action which was careful or perceived to be wise.

Properly used as here, oxymoron does not introduce error into writing.